# kendo-angular-chart not found dependency kendo-charts-1.19.1.tgz

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-angular-ui

does anyone have the same problem with kendo-chart?
I'm trying to install kendo-angular-chart and i have this issue:

```
npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-charts/-/kendo-charts-1.19.1.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@progress/kendo-charts@^1.15.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@progress/kendo-angular-charts'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a network issue causing the described problem. Please try reinstalling the node modules, everything should be working as expected now.